# Radeon ReLive only records a green screen, how do i fix it?

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, recording

Okay, so I have been trying to setup my Radeon ReLive and I got it all working and the setting to where I wanted them. However when I am playing Rainbow Six Siege on Windows 10 and I use the Instant Replay function, when I go to the file it records the sound but it only shows me a green screen. How do I go about fixing this? I have looked online and I haven't been able to find any long term solutions.

My current driver version is: **18.7.1**
My current Graphics card is: **AMD Radeon R9 390 Series**

If you need any other information just ask in the comment, I really want to see this working! Also sorry if this isn't the right place to ask, I didn't know where else to ask.

**EDIT:** Here are pictures of my configuration

[[image]Global Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOGiq.png)

[[image]Recording Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbPLQ.png)

[[image]Streaming Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQDP8.png)

[[image]Overlay Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dv1z.png)

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/DH-023.aspx) and let us know which settings you are using. For troubleshooting see  [this article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/8alrao/to_those_having_issues_with_amd_relive_not/).

Comment: Exactly what setting are you wanting to know?

Comment: All the settings mentioned in the article that apply to your case.

Comment: But that's just it, I don't know what settings apply to ReLive

Comment: Just include in your post the screenshots in Radeon ReLive Settings of the tabs of Global, Recording, Streaming and  Overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radeon ReLive gets some negative reviews for recording on the one hand,
and on the other hand Rainbow Six Siege is said to be difficult to record.
So a bad combination.

Here is some advice that you may try.
Undo the ones which do not help.

1. In Setting, Streaming tab, disable Stage Ten.
2. In Global tab, disable Frame Rate Target Control
3. [Disable Windows 10’s Game DVR and Game Bar](https://www.howtogeek.com/273180/how-to-disable-windows-10s-game-dvr-and-game-bar/)
4. In Recording tab, reduce Recording Profile and also Recording FPS
5. Turn off VSync in Rainbow Siege Six.

The following article describes the Settings of Radeon ReLive in detail:
[How to Capture Your Gameplay Using Radeon™ ReLive](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/DH-023.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Wallpaper Enginge **can** be a issue. Disable Wallpaper Engine to test it.
Otherwise, it fixed it for me just to **reinstall the AMD Drivers** (with the Radeon Software of course).

I know its almost two year over since this Question has been asked, but i just wanted to share my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It's August 2020 and I had the same issue, Mine was with the setting called "Radeon Anti-Lag". Under Gaming go to Graphics then Global then Scroll down and Disable Radeon anti-lag